# Outlook adding horizontal whiteline to neighbouring <td>, when the other <td> wraps into multiple lines

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have a very simple html email template:

```
        <table
          cellpadding="0"
          cellspacing="0"
          width="100%"
          style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #dadada"
        >
          <tr style="height: 6px; font-size: 6px">
            <td style="line-height: 5px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width: 100%">
            <!-- LEFT MARGIN OF CONTENT -->
            <td style="width: 12px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="font-size: 14px">{{content}}</td>
            <!-- RIGHT MARGIN OF CONTENT -->
            <td style="width: 12px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="height: 6px; font-size: 6px">
            <td style="line-height: 5px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Everything works well until the < td > with the {{content}} placeholder wraps into multiple lines. In such case, white lines appear in the neighbouring < td > tags, like this:

[image]

I tried multiple solutions like adding styles like line-height, background color or border: 0 or rowspan=10 to try and make the line disappear, but nothing works. What's more, if I change the Outlook zoom value from 100% to 110%, the white lines disappear, but then again appear at that zoom level, if the middle < td > is taking only single line.

I am aware that the white horizontal lines in Outlook are a common issue, but none of the many resources online helped me with my specific case, where I use neighbouring < td > tags to work as horizontal margin.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your table in another table>tr>td and move your bgcolor there as an overarching container. This will effectively make your white lines from your tds not visible.

You can also check to make sure all your numbered declarations are even numbers.
For example, making your line-height 4px or 6px.

Outlook can be very weird with how it renders odd-numbered declarations. In my experience this is usually the cause of the dreaded Outlook white-lines.

Here is a useful article that supports this.

[https://help.contactmonkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050009651-Why-Are-There-Thin-Horizontal-Lines-Showing-Up-In-My-Emails-#:~:text=These%20lines%20are%20commonly%20visible,relative%20to%20the%20device%20view.&text=Outlook%20will%20sometimes%20add%20a,to%200%20to%20avoid%20this](https://help.contactmonkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050009651-Why-Are-There-Thin-Horizontal-Lines-Showing-Up-In-My-Emails-#:%7E:text=These%20lines%20are%20commonly%20visible,relative%20to%20the%20device%20view.&text=Outlook%20will%20sometimes%20add%20a,to%200%20to%20avoid%20this).